# Incomplete map comes back from tile server, more tiles available at zoom level than docs indicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, geospatial

I'm using AngularJS, Leaflet, and Angular-leaflet-directive in the following example which I got from the Angular-leaflet-directive project.  This example works when using public tile servers, including the public ArcGIS server the example is currently pointing to.

According to several online sources of documentation, including these two from [open street maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers) and [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-web-maps-work/), the number of tiles available at a particular zoom level should be 2^z X 2^z, where z is the zoom level.  So, at zoom level 0 we should get 1 tile, at 1 we should get 4 tiles, and so on.

The issue I have only occurs when pointing to a privately hosted (corporate intranet) ESRI ArcGIS tile server.  When I try to view the page below as is, but with the private tile server's url instead of the http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}, I only see partial maps at zoom level 0 and 1.

After poking around a little bit I realized that the tile server wants to send two tile instead of 1 at zoom level 0, 6 tiles instead of 4 at zoom level 1.  And the problem continues at deeper zoom levels.  When looking at the urls for the individual tiles (for example ../0/0/0 and ../0/0/1 at zoom level 0), I see that we do get the composite map we expect if we put together remaining tiles which are available at that zoom level.  Meaning if leaflet wanted to build the entire map the information is available.

I am very new to Leaflet and Maps in general, but I feel that by telling leaflet to expect more tiles at a given zoom level, it should be able to get the complete picture, but after searching leaflet documentation, I was unable to find such a configuration.

My questions: is there such a setting?  If so what is it?  Maybe the question is missing something or I don't know enough to ask the right question.  Am I looking at the right documentation?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ width: 900px; height: 500px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

  // load a tile layer
   L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    {
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe the question is missing something or I don't know enough to ask the right question.

I think you're missing the concept of map projections. If a map is using EPSG:3857, then chances are that the zoom 0 is covered by 1 tile. If it's in EPSG:4326, then it's 2 tiles.

Compare these (static) images from leaflet maps of NASA's Blue Marble:

[image: Map in EPSG:3857]
[image: Map in EPSG:4326]

Both are correct, but they use different projections (EPSG:3857 on top and EPSG:4326 on bottom).

I **strongly** suggest you research what projection your tiles are using. You might need a bit of extra research on map projections and even Proj4Leaflet to get it working, but at least you know ehre to look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on comments from @IvanSanchez.  Note that I'm pointing to a public server that serves up EPSG:4326 and adding crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326 to defaults.  One important point to note is that this is not fully supported by the current stable version of leaflet (0.7.7).  In order to get it to work, I upgraded to 1.0.0 Beta2.  For more information on this issue, including alternative to using the beta version, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1207.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="lib/angular-1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-leaflet-directive-master/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
        app.controller('BasicCustomParametersController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                london: {
                    lat: 51.505,
                    lng: -0.09,
                    zoom: 1,
                    noWrap: false,
                    minZoom: 1,
                    maxZoom: 10
                },
                defaults: {
                   //EPSG:3857
                   // tileLayer: "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",

                   //EPSG:4326
                    tileLayer: "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",

                    zoomControlPosition: 'topright',
                    tileLayerOptions: {
                        opacity: 0.9,
                        detectRetina: true,
                        reuseTiles: true,
                    },
                    scrollWheelZoom: false,

                   //use EPSG4326.  Not fully supported in leaflet 0.7.7.  Works with 1.0.0 Beta2
                    crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326
                }
            });
        }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="BasicCustomParametersController">
    <leaflet lf-center="london" defaults="defaults" width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
    <h1>Using custom default parameters</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```